# Issue creating new Table with AspNetBoilerPlate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using the latest version of ABP v3_6_1. I created two a Table as ObdMaster and pushed it to DB.

```
    [Table("ObdMaster")]
    public class ObdMaster : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMayHaveTenant, IPassivable, ICreationAudited
    {
        public const int NumbersLimit = 50;
        public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 64 * 1024; //64KB

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(NumbersLimit)]
        public string ObdNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(NumbersLimit)]
        public string SimImeiNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(NumbersLimit)]
        public string SimNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public int? TenantId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Table gets created just fine via migrations.
I created a Service as

```
    public class ObdMasterAppService : TrackingSystemAppServiceBase, IObdMasterAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<ObdMaster> _obdRepository;

        public ObdMasterAppService(IRepository<ObdMaster> repository)
        {
            _obdRepository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<ListResultDto<ObdMaster>> GetAll(GetAllObdMasterInput input)
        {
            var tasks = await _obdRepository
                .GetAll()
                .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Type), t => t.Type == input.Type)
                .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Protocol), t => t.Protocol == input.Protocol)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreationTime)
                .ToListAsync();

            return new ListResultDto<ObdMaster>(
                ObjectMapper.Map<List<ObdMaster>>(tasks)
            );
        }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IObdMasterAppService : IApplicationService
    {
        Task<ListResultDto<ObdMaster>> GetAll(GetAllObdMasterInput input);
        Task<ObdMaster> Create(CreateObdMasterDto input);
    }
```

Now for the GetAll Method, as per sql profiler, it fires a query as below for one Tenant:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[CreationTime], [t].[CreatorUserId], [t].[DeleterUserId], [t].[DeletionTime], [t].[Description], [t].[IsActive], [t].[IsDeleted], [t].[LastModificationTime], [t].[LastModifierUserId], [t].[ObdNumber], [t].[Protocol], [t].[SimImeiNumber], [t].[SimNumber], [t].[TenantId], [t].[Type]
FROM [ObdMaster] AS [t]
WHERE (([t].[IsDeleted] = 0) OR ([t].[IsDeleted] <> @__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0)) AND ([t].[TenantId] IS NULL OR (CASE
    WHEN [t].[TenantId] IS NULL
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END = @__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3))
ORDER BY [t].[CreationTime] DESC',N'@__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0 bit,@__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3 bit',@__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0=1,@__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3=1
```

AND below for another Tenant:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[CreationTime], [t].[CreatorUserId], [t].[DeleterUserId], [t].[DeletionTime], [t].[Description], [t].[IsActive], [t].[IsDeleted], [t].[LastModificationTime], [t].[LastModifierUserId], [t].[ObdNumber], [t].[Protocol], [t].[SimImeiNumber], [t].[SimNumber], [t].[TenantId], [t].[Type]
FROM [ObdMaster] AS [t]
WHERE (([t].[IsDeleted] = 0) OR ([t].[IsDeleted] <> @__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0)) AND (([t].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_1) OR (CASE
    WHEN [t].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END = @__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3))
ORDER BY [t].[CreationTime] DESC',N'@__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0 bit,@__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_1 int,@__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2 int,@__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3 bit',@__ef_filter__IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled_0=1,@__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_1=6,@__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2=6,@__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_3=1
```

I can see that table definition etc is the same for both the Tenants. I am using the same repository.
For ist query, I am getting desired data but not with the 2nd query. 
Any idea on what's wrong I am doing?

Comment: What's not desired?

Comment: I am getting all the record with 1st query but no data with 2nd query. Just to update, First DB created using Update-Database works fine but any new Database created using Create new Tenant is having the problem.

Comment: SOLVED--- I was inserting the tenantId as null while creating the records. Since tenantId of the first Tenant is null it works there but not with subsequently created Tenants.